# C# decompiling class with enumerator

Tags: c#, decompiling

I'm trying to decompile a c# dll and on a particular method I'm getting this result

```
public IEnumerable<Guid> GetDbIdentifiers(int classId)
{
    switch ((794999935 == 794999935) ? 1 : 0)
    {
    case 0:
    case 2:
        IL_1E:
        break;
    case 1:
        goto IL_1F;
    }
    goto IL_1E;
    IL_1F:
    if (0 == 0)
    {
    }
    if (1 == 0)
    {
    }
    int arg_2E_0 = 0;
    DatabaseHandler.Class106 @class = new DatabaseHandler.Class106(-2);
    @class.databaseHandler_0 = this;
    @class.int_3 = classId;
    return @class;
}
```

It's calling a inner class Class106 inside DatabaseHandler, but it seems it cannot decompile this inner class.

I tried dotPeek, ILSpy, JustDecompile and Reflector.

The best result I got was with Reflector, it decompiled the class partially. The definition is this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class Class106 : IDisposable, IEnumerable<Guid>, IEnumerator<Guid>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator
```

I read in many forums that Enumerators are decompiled as inner classes and no decompiler can produce usable code. It seems the case, since the Class106 implements IEnumerable and IEnumerator interfaces.

Does anyone have any clue on how I could patch this manually?

Comment: It might of been obfuscated to make decompilation difficult. I.e. the person who wrote this doesn't want you to decompile it.

Comment: This is pretty obviously obfuscated code; the redundant switch on `(794999935 == 794999935) ? 1 : 0` (which is a fancy way of writing `1`) and the "difficult" names for locals (`@class`) are dead giveaways. The only thing that can reliably pick such code apart is `ildasm`, and that requires that you're good at reading IL rather than pseudo-C#. (ILSpy and I'm pretty sure Reflector also have modes for displaying the raw IL rather than C#.)